# Zend_Soap - Error parsing WSDL: Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap-client, zend-soap

For the same WSDL, which is totally valid, I am able to access it properly using PEAR SOAP like this:

```
$WSDL = new SOAP_WSDL($this->wsdlUrl);
$proxy = $WSDL->getProxy();
```

But not able to make it work through Zend_Soap, when used like this:

```
$soapclient = new Zend_Soap_Client($this->wsdlUrl);
```

I get the following error when accessed through Zend_Soap_Client:

> Error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load 
>   from 'https://abc.xyz.com/agent/TestService.php?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Openssl is also enabled in my php.ini
Does anybody know why it doesn't work? and how I can fix it to use Zend_Soap properly?

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the ssl-Certificate is valid. This Error Message is also thrown if ssl-certificate verification fails.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that no Ports are blocked in your hosting situation.
I've had the same error, though with different code just plain php, and was struggling with it for several days.

It turned out that my webhotel had blocked the port I needed to access the web service.
Or it could some proxy-related issue giving the same blocked result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HTTP Authentication? Auth works with SOAP Client, however you cannot access password protected WSDL files

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27777